# recursive list function in lisp that finds number of times a was present in list

Tags: recursion, lisp, common-lisp

;Question 3

```
(defun listcheck(lst)
  (cond
   ((not (null lst))
    (cond
     ((eq (car lst) 'a) (+ (listcheck (cdr lst)) 1))
     ( T (listcheck (cdr lst)))
     )
    )
   )
  0
  )
```

this function prints out 0 at all times not sure where im going wrong any input would help

Comment: Because it ends with `0`.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your question or make vandalizing suggested edits to its answers.

Answer (score 2):

It's printing `0` because the function ends with `0`, outside the `cond`. So it returns this in all cases, not just the base of the recursion. That should only be returned when `lst` is null.

```
(defun listcheck(lst)
  (cond ((null lst) 0)
        ((eq (car lst) 'a) (+ (listcheck (cdr lst)) 1))
        (T (listcheck (cdr lst)))))
```